# How to create (not switch) Datasource, JdbcTemplate and TransactionManager instance at runtime?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions

My Spring Boot application doesn't know which database to connect to at the start of the application. It will receive the input in the HTTP request body (that includes dbtype,dbservername etc) at runtime and it should connect to a DB instance based on this input.

For similar questions that I checked on StackOverflow, people have suggested ways to create Datasource instances beforehand and then switch during runtime based on the input. However, I don't want to hardcode configurations for different DBs. I want the application to create the JdbcTemplate, Datasource, and TransactionManager instances at runtime.

Here's what I have tried so far to create the JdbcTemplate and Datasource instance at runtime:

```
class DBConfig{
    private DataSource getMSSQLDatasource(String servername){
        // create MSSQL datasource using the servername
    }

    private DataSource getDB2Datasource(String servername){
        // create DB2 datasource using the servername
    }

    private JdbcTemplate setJdbcTemplate(String dbtype, String servername){
        return new JdbcTemplate(dbtype.equals("DB2") ? getDB2Datasource(servername) : getMSSQLDatasource(servername));
    }
}
```

So I can create JdbcTemplate and Datasource at runtime.
But I also want to execute some of the queries as a transaction using @Transactional for which I would need a TransactionManager.
I am not sure how to configure it dynamically at runtime.

So I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to configure TransactionManager dynamically (just like I have done with JdbcTemplate)? If so How?
2. Any suggestions?

Comment: How is this information provided at runtime? A gui? Parameters while starting the application? How. As long as the information is provided before the beans are created you don't need to do anything. Please provide a bit more context on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @M.Deinum The input will be passed in the HTTP request body. So the controller will receive the input. Have updated the question.

Comment: @Foos Can you elaborate on why you don't want to switch connections? Once used, do you want to remove these instantiated beans again? Do you want pooled connections? Why factors made you decide not to simply switch at runtime? How many different datasources etc could potentially be created?

Comment: @NicoVanBelle So this application is a utility. Currently, It needs to handle 2 dbms in 3 different environments. So at any point in time, it would need to connect to 1 of the 6 (2X3=6) db instances. But in future, we might add more dbms or environments. In that case, I would have to add the configuration for those instances. So just to make my life a bit easier, I want to make the configuration a bit flexible.

Comment: Is this a one time operation? Is this persistent, or each time the application starts? Can you switch while having one or the other?

Comment: @M.Deinum It's a one-time operation. Once the application starts, the configuration should be done and that's it, every time a query is executed, it will happen on the single db instance only. So no switching after that.

Comment: Does it need to persist between restarts?

Comment: @M.Deinum No it doesn't

Comment: You could make your app a 2 step process. First start the basic web application without anything. Let that provide the information, then start a new spring boot application which acts as a child of the first one, passing in the provided url, username, password as regular `spring.datasource.*` properties to the child context. This will then start the remainder of the application.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried a workaround that I have added as an answer. Can you please comment on that?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a workaround and it seems to be working fine so far. **Any suggestions would be really helpful**.

Created a custom class (DynamicTransactionManager) that implements PlatformTransactionManager:

```
@Component
class DynamicTransactionManager implements PlatformTransactionManager{
    private DataSource datasource;
    private DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager;

    public void setDatasource(DataSource datasource){
        this.datasource = datasource;
        this.transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
    }

    @Override
    public TransactionStatus getTransaction (TransactionDefinition definition) throws TransactionException { 
        return transactionManager.getTransaction (definition);
    }

    @Override
    public void commit (TransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException {
        transactionManager.commit(status);
    }

    @Override
    public void rollback(TransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException {
        transactionManager.rollback(status);
    }
}
```

Now in the DBConfig class, while creating JdbcTemplate, access DynamicTransactionManager's bean and set the DataSource dynamically like this:

```
class DBConfig{
    private DataSource getMSSQLDatasource(String servername){
        // create MSSQL datasource using the servername
    }

    private DataSource getDB2Datasource(String servername){
        // create DB2 datasource using the servername
    }

    private JdbcTemplate setJdbcTemplate(String dbtype, String servername){
        DataSource datasource = dbtype.equals("DB2") ? getDB2Datasource(servername) : getMSSQLDatasource(servername);
        
        // CONFIGURE TRANSACTION MANAGER
        DynamicTransactionManager transactionManager = applicationContext.getBean(DynamicTransactionManager.class); 
        transactionManager.setDataSource(datasource);
        
        return new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
    }
}
```

So basically DynamicTransactionManager's bean is getting created at the start of the application (because of @Component) but the transaction manager inside it is not initialized.

At runtime, while creating the JdbcTemplate in the DBConfig, I am extracting the bean of class DynamicTransactionManager from applicationContext and injecting the DataSource into this bean using the setDatasource method.